# Debugging discrepancy between authentication in firebase app and rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an app using Firebase Auth and Firestore.

I have the current code to create a game document:

```js
export const createGame = async () => {
  const title = makeid(6);
  const myDoc = doc(db, "rides", title);
  const payload = {
    createdBy: auth.currentUser.uid
  };
  console.log(title, payload, auth.currentUser);
  await setDoc(myDoc, payload);
  return title;
};
```

This results in the following being printed to the console:

```bash
5YTm0R {createdBy: 'pLCzrgwSQSa9KxaW5OlU2l18CGY2'} UserImpl {providerId: 'firebase', proactiveRefresh: ProactiveRefresh, reloadUserInfo: {…}, reloadListener: null, uid: 'pLCzrgwSQSa9KxaW5OlU2l18CGY2', …}
```

As you can see from the log, the current user exists. It is an anonymous user, so `isAnonymous` is true when you expand the object.

However, the request fails, and when I look at the emulator's console, I see the following image:

[image: current user null]

The current user is being shown as `null` in the Firebase Emulator console whereas it is non-null in the application.

I'm wondering if there's a particular set of steps I need to take for Firestore to use the current user's authentication when making a request? Thanks!

Comment: can we have the entire line 8 from the rules please ?

Comment: The problem wound up fixing itself by upgrading to the newest firebase. Sorry for the noise! Maybe my only recommendation would be to have something in the UI that recommends upgrades when this sort of issue arises. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Posting as community wiki:

As per @mikesol, the issue was resolved by upgrading to the newest Firebase version.

```
npm i firebase@latest
```